# Handling an error in a template method

Tags: c++, templates, error-handling, return, return-value

I am having a problem finding a good solution for handling an error in this template function.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
const V& DirectHashmap<K, V>::lookup(K key) const
{
    int pos = position(key);

    return _values.get(pos)->value;
}
```

I can't return an error code because I don't know the type I am returning. I prefer not to use exceptions because we never used exceptions in the project before and it would not be consistent if this were the only method with a exception.

If someone has a good solution please let me know! All feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `std::pair<bool, V&>`?

Comment: Return a `optional<V&>`?

Comment: may be return bool isFound, and accept second parameter V& by reference, and update it with found object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead return a `const_iterator` to your collection.

The end user can test to see if it's equivalent to `.end()` for your collection. This is how the containers in the STL typically work. (refer to [map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), [unordered_map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find), and [unordered_set::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find))

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with C++14 we now have template variables which you can use to let the client code define the error for a type as in the example code. In practice I wouldn't make them globals but have some namespace the client can open which the template function will know about.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T error;

template<>
int error<int> = -1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << error<int> << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```